# Does replication overwrite changes to the slave?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am trying to find an explanation to the outdated data on the slave.
There is a set up of a master server A and two slaves B and C.

A recent change was replicated everywhere, except one table on B. Table B contains a lot of data, and stuff gets replicated every day correctly, slave is working, 0 seconds behind master.

***I have a theory***: Can a change to a row on the slave prevent the row from getting overwritten by the replication?

If yes, that would explain the issue.
Primary key hasn't been modified, all other rows in this table replicate normally.

P.S.: I was able to find that inserting a new row or changing the id can break the replication, but I wasn't able to find the answer to this question

Details:

- Slave has a system time stamp of x. There might have been a change at that time, not by me.
- Master was changed at x+6seconds (Not Primary key change, simple update to one of the fields). Running the script that does it changed two tables: one for an object, one for it's timings
- Change was not replicated to ONE of the slaves, only the object table contained incorrect info.
- Master was changed again at x+15minutes to see if this would overwrite slave
- Change wasn't replicated to ONE of the slaves, timings table correct, but the object row not.

Comment: Yes. Slaves have to be regarded as readonly. If you change data on the slave, it might (or might not) break replication. So don't do it (unless you plan your setup accordingly).

Comment: I did not, I am trying to find out what broke it. Thank you

Comment: You said: "Can a change to a row on the slave prevent the row from getting overwritten by the replication?". The answer is yes, if you change a row on the slave (= change data), it can result in problems with replication, because the replication acts as if you treat the slave as read-only. If I understood your comment correctly, you seem to have changed that row, or didn't you? You can try to manually change the row on your slave to match your server again (with the risk of missing things that this row might have had influcence on in earlier replicated queries) or reinitialize your slave.

Comment: I did not change anything on the slave. This is a production sized database, and I am not the only person who has access to it. I want to know if a change to a row that does not affect Primary Key can cause the row to be out of sync. Every other row and other tables sync normally